# Архитектура - настройки как отдельный проект

Tags: архитектура

Столкнулся с ситуацией когда настройки приложения стали очень сложными. Все хранить в конфиге стало не просто не удобно но и очень проблематично. встал вопрос вообще вынести все в отдельный проект и хранить все в json, как вариант. Возможно есть другие варианты или более гибкие решения. Буду благодарен за совет.

Comment: Краткость — сестра олимпиадника. Можете более подробно и нудно/скучно описать ситуацию? Если ваш конфиг по своему смыслу сперва был хэшем, но потом развился в дерево, то да, храните его в JSON или XML. Есть и другие варианты. Мне, например, нравятся конфиги с фигурными скобками, где не надо заключать строки в кавычки.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov - есть с десяток проектов. Есть как общий скоуп настроек с одинаковыми значениями - например адрес сервиса для получения списка клиентов один для всех. Есть уникальные данные для каждого проекта, тут например, адреса отличаются. Либо же для одного проекта нужны настройки сессии другому что то еще. Так вот, возникло желание, вынести все это в отдельный проект так, что бы все другие проекты использовали одну конфигурабельную библиотеку настроек. В будущем, может также возникнуть ситуация, когда возвращаемое значение будет зависеть от того, кто запросил и с какими параметрами.

Comment: вроде бы (если я все понял) получается так, что есть общий конфиг, в котором хранятся опции по умолчанию, и для каждого проекта есть индивидуальный конфиг, в котором эти опции можно перезаписать. На этом шаге отдельный проект (сервер конфигураций) все еще не нужен. А вот дальше, что касается "кто запросил и с какими параметрами" - уже нужно отдельное приложение, которое генерирует конфиги в зависимости от параметров. Но это может быть просто скрипт, а не приложение в терминах вашей IDE.